# Scraping with simple.html.dom and placing the results into an array

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i don't know if my title is correct feel free to correct me, but i have a simple issue. My code is working fine and i am getting the results that i want, but i want them in an array. For example:`[0] => Description: Sentinel. Winged Guardian cannot have restricted attachments. Forced: After an attack in which Winged Guardian defends resolves, pay 1 Tactics resource or discard Winged Guardian from play.`

`[1] => Description: Attach to a hero. Attached hero gains +1 Attack. Action: Pay 1 resource from attached hero&#39;s pool to attach Dunedain Mark to another hero.`

This is my code:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url="http://hallofbeorn.com/LotR?CardSet=The+Hunt+for+Gollum";
$html=file_get_html($url);

   foreach ($html->find('div[style="margin-left:2px;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;"]') as $values) {
        echo $values->plaintext;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$url="http://hallofbeorn.com/LotR?CardSet=The+Hunt+for+Gollum";
$html=file_get_html($url);

$html_arr = [];

foreach ($html->find('div[style="margin-left:2px;vertical-align:top;text-align:left;"]') as $values) {
           $html_arr[] = $values->plaintext;
         }

print_r($html_arr);
```